# financial chart auto update javascript

Tags: javascript, chart.js, finance, stockquotes

I'm currently trying to get better in JavaScript and I decided challenging myself into making a website where you can track a stock portfolio. I have managed to get the chart I want with Chart.js and HTML/CSS, but the challenge now is to have it pull information about stock prices in "real-time". So the problem I'm facing is that I want to change my chart to be based on price information available online instead of having to update it myself by writing a new datapoint every time I want to update it! Underneath is the code I'm using for the chart!

```
    <script src="Chart.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"> . 
    </script>

    <script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("portChart").getContext("2d");
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        type: "line",
        data: {
            labels: ["October", "November", "December", "January", "February", "March", "April"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "My First Portfolio",
                backgroundColor: "white",
                borderColor: "black",
                fill: false,
                data: [100, 93, 94, 100, 110, 111, 116],
            }, {
            label: "OSEBX",
                backgroundColor: "white",
                borderColor: "red",
                fill: false,
                data: [100, 101, 101, 105, 100, 103, 105],
            }
        ]
        },
        options: {}
    });
</script>
```

Sorry for the really noob question, but I'm kinda stuck so I really appreciate any input regarding which way to proceed!

Comment: Have you accomplished pulling the stock information from whatever site you get your information?

Comment: Hi Matt! No, that's where I'm stuck! I'm having problems with finding and using an API so that the data is pulled automatically, instead of me having to manually add data-points to the array "data" for the timeseries "My First Portfolio" and "OSEBX"!